# I have got this error when i run python manage.py makemigrations

Tags: python, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I got this error when is makemigrations

The databe setting for database in setting.py is:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'freecodeschool',
        'USER': 'fcs_admin',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

when i run migrations i got this error.

```
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 187, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

and when i supply the password then it give me this error.

```
   connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "fcs_admin"
FATAL:  password authentication
```

Comment: The error message states the exact issue you're having. `no password supplied`

Comment: also you need to specify your port as well.

Comment: but i supply the password and port i give me this error.      connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/danish-khan/django_drf/django/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "fcs_admin"
FATAL:  password authentication

Comment: @Akashsenta It's not needed. From the docs: *"An empty string, or an empty item in a comma-separated list, specifies the default port number"*

Comment: @DanishKhan : first you must try to connect with cmd or pgadmin with that username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you haven't filled PASSWORD and your db wants it for user "fcs_admin". beside that you should add your db PORT too. (default is 5432)
if you're not sure about postgres users' password you can use these commands:

```
sudo su postgres
\du
```

Comment: i edited here is       '**DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'freecodeschool',
        'USER': 'fcs_admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'danish3210',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}**
'    but again got the sme error:      conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "fcs_admin"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "fcs_admin"

Comment: make sure you fill the password right using above commands.

Comment: Thanks i set the password in psql set admin password and now it starts working.